# Reduce repetition in SCSS for panels of various colors

Tags: sass

I have the following SCSS and I'm curious as to how I can improve it, and reduce the amount of repetition...

I plan on adding more colors, but I don't wish to keep copy/pasting the same block over and over.

```
.panel-alt {
    &.panel-default {
        border-color: $btn-default-bg;
        > .panel-body {
            background-color: $btn-default-bg;
        }
    }
    &.panel-primary > .panel-body {
        border-color: $brand-primary;
        > .panel-body {
            background-color: $brand-primary;
        }
    }
    &.panel-success > .panel-body {
        border-color: $brand-success;
        > .panel-body {
            background-color: $brand-success;
        }
    }
    &.panel-info > .panel-body {
        border-color: $brand-info;
        > .panel-body {
            background-color: $brand-info;
        }
    }
    &.panel-warning > .panel-body {
        border-color: $brand-warning;
        > .panel-body {
            background-color: $brand-warning;
        }
    }
    &.panel-danger > .panel-body {
        border-color: $brand-danger;
        > .panel-body {
            background-color: $brand-danger;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I create [a demo in codepen.io](http://codepen.io/jamespr/pen/OPZEwp) in order to display how your SCSS could be used. Feel free to clarify anything on the demo. If I understand your intentions clearly the rule `.panel-body` on all `&.panel-xxx > .panel-body` declarations are not necessary. Also, in case that you need to support IE6/7, CSS adjoining classes are not supported on IE6/7. Apart from that, nice code.

Comment: -1. I'm downvoting because your answer says nothing about the reasoning behind your code. You're simply allowing the OP to copy and paste, which isn't a great habit to foster.

Comment: I'll work on that @AlexL. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It's ok to link to codepen, but links rot, so the content should be included here too. I downvoted too, but after you incorporate the code, and make the improvements suggested by Alex, I'll be happy to reverse that (maybe even turn into an upvote).